# PHP: elementos com e sem chaves explicitas numa mesma array

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando descobrir uma forma melhor ou mais limpa de fazer algo assim em PHP:

```
// Isto será passado como argumento de uma função...
$params = array('Nome', 'Idade', 'Mail' => 'algum@mail.com');
```

"Nome" e "Idade" são valores com chaves atribuídas automaticamente (0 e 1, por exemplo), e "Mail" é uma chave com o valor "algum@mail.com":

```
[0] => 'Nome',
[1] => 'Idade',
['Mail'] => 'algum@mail.com'
```

Quando eu passo isso por um loop "foreach", estou fazendo isso para ter "Nome" e "Idade" como os parâmetros de fato:

```
foreach ($params as $k => $i) {

    // Esta é a parte "feia"!
    if (is_int($k)) {
        $k = $i;
        $i = false;
    }

    // Para fazer algo assim, por exemplo...
    $out = "";
    if ($i) {
        $out .= "<p><a href=\"mailto:$i\">$k</a></p>\n";
    } else {
        $out .= "<p>$k<p>\n";
    }

}
```

O que irá retornar algo assim:

```
<p>Name</p>
<p>Age</p>
<p><a href="mailto:some@mail.com">Mail</a></p>
```

A questão é: existe uma forma limpa do PHP diferenciar os elementos de uma mesma array que possuem uma chave explícita (Mail => algum@email.com) dos que não possuem (Nome e Idade)?

**Observação:** o código acima foi dividido em duas etapas para melhor entendimento da solução atual, que é diferenciar o valor da chave testando se ele é uma integer, mas o código que estou usando na verdade é:

```
$o = "";
foreach ($params as $k => $i) {
    if (!is_int($k)) {
        $o .= "<p><a href=\"$i\">$k</a></p>\n";
    } else {
        $o .= "<p>$i</p>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Não seria mais intuitivo ter `array('Nome'=>null, 'Idade'=>null, 'Mail' => 'algum@mail.com')`?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim, se este procedimento não estivesse dentro de uma função genérica para, por exemplo, criar linhas de uma tabela, onde a tag "td" poderia ou não ter parâmetros adicionais. O ideal seria: funcao_tal('nome', 'idade', array('mail' => 'um@mail.com')), mas não sei se existe uma forma do PHP entender que a quantidade de argumentos da função pode variar. Ao mesmo tempo, passar todo o argumento como uma única string e fatiá-lo depois seria igualmente sujo. Veja também que estou querendo aproveitar o novo formato de arrays do PHP>=3.4 "[elementos]", por uma questão de legibilidade.

Comment: Não entendo o que você quer dizer com sujo? Por não ser dinâmico? Não vejo problema algum nisso, talvez seja só gosto pessoal seu.

Comment: Para capturar os argumentos: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.func-get-args.php

Comment: @Marcelo Aymone, eu acabei de descobrir isso e de fato é a solução. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Fico feliz que isto ajudou a encontrar a resposta, abração!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao que tudo indica, a resposta para a pergunta original é mesmo **não**, não existe um modo do PHP diferenciar elementos com e sem chaves dentro de uma mesma array.

Mas, o problema original derivava da necessidade de criar uma função legível onde a quantidade de argumentos passados poderia variar, daí a opção inicial por uma array, que permitiria uma chamada assim:

```
add_table_row(['Nome', 'Idade', 'Mail' => 'um@mail.com']);
```

ou assim...

```
add_table_row(array('Nome', 'Idade', 'Mail' => 'um@mail.com'));
```

Contudo, como acabei de descobrir, existe uma forma de passar uma quantidade variável de argumentos para uma função, utilizando a função "func_get_args()", e a chamada da função pode ficar ainda mais legível:

```
// PHP >= 5.4
add_table_row('Nome', 'Idade', ['Mail' => 'um@mail.com']);
```

ou

```
add_table_row('Nome', 'Idade', array('Mail' => 'um@mail.com'));
```

Portanto, um exemplo do código completo da função seria algo assim:

```
function add_table_row() {
    $args = func_get_args(); // retorna uma array de argumentos...
    $o = "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($args as $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {       // Se o argumento é uma array...
            $cont = key($value);      // O dado da célula é a chave...
            $param = current($value); // E o parâmetro da tag é o valor...
            $o .= "<td $param>$cont</td>\n";
        } else {
            $o .= "<td>$value</td>\n";
        }
    }
    $o .= "</tr>\n";
    return $o;
}
```

Espero que isso seja útil a mais alguém.

Comment: isso é permitido sim. Escolha sua própria resposta como resolvendo o problema

Comment: Outra maneira bem comum é passar uma única array para a função, com outras dentro se necessário. Por exemplo: `add_table_row(['Nome', 'Idade', ['Mail' => 'um@mail.com']]);`. Dentro da função, você pode checar se cada um dos itens é outra array com `is_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Já que você vai criar uma função para isso, você pode passar como string e encontrar os elementos marcadores... Basta explodir nas `,` e se houver `:` a função vai entender que é um array.
`add_table_row('Nome,Idade,Mail:um@mail.com')`

```
    function add_table_row( $string )
    {
        $string = explode( ',' , $string );

        foreach( $string as $line )
        {
            if( strpos( $line , ':' ) && $elementos = explode( ':' , $line ) )
            {
                echo $elementos[0] . ', ' . $elementos[1];
            }
            else
            {
                echo $line;
            }
        }
    }
```

> **output**
>   <sub>Nome
>
>   Idade
>
>   Mail, um@mail.com</sub>

Comment: esse foi o meu primeiro impulso, até porque geralmente eu uso e abuso das implosões, explosões e outras operações com strings. Só que isso implica em processar os dados duas vezes: na preparação da string dos argumentos e na "decodificação" dentro da função. Já usando uma array (ou com func_get_args(), como foi minha escolha), eu só preciso preparar os dados para a função, que por sua vez fica muito mais limpa, objetiva e legível, eu acho. Mas a sua solução é tão boa quanto qualquer outra.